# How to show firebase stored image with image URL on ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Trying to code a ListView Activity that will display the names and the pictures that's stored on my Firebase Storage.

I have that condition in my Firebase:

[image]

I want to show this image using the image URL. I had no success using:

```
Picasso.with(ImagesActivity.this).load(std.getmImageUrl()).into(imageView);
```

My ListView code:

```
adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull Object model, int position) {

            TextView name = v.findViewById(R.id.name_tv);
            ImageView imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTV);

            Upload std = (Upload) model;
            name.setText(std.getName());

            Picasso.with(ImagesActivity.this).load(std.getmImageUrl()).into(imageView);
        }
    };
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I created "Upload.class" to get the image URL:

```
    public Upload(String name, String imageUrl){

    if (name.trim().equals("")){
        name = "No Name";
    }

    this.mName = name;
    this.mImageUrl = imageUrl;
}
```

The images are not displayed on the ImageView of ListView activity.

Comment: You can either use glide or Picasso library to load image URLs  Picasso : https://square.github.io/picasso/.      Glide :  https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: I have done it, its still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the image url . Please check logs.

Comment: `textview` and `imageview` are not displaying or just `imageview` ? and what is size of  Images ?

Comment: Only the image, the size doesn't matter I guess because it displays it on the profile picture. I tried coping the URL by R-Click and changed the mImageURL value to it and it displays it fine, the others that I didn't change doesn't show up for some reason.

Comment: that is uri , try :
            Picasso.with(ImagesActivity.this).load(Uri.prase(std.getmImageUrl())).into(imageView);

Comment: edit: works thanks :)